# Prove a polynomial in Fq is a permutation polynomial of Fqn with a necessary and sufficient condition

Tags: polynomials, permutations, finite-fields

P.S This is the best Math Expression I can edit. I am real shameful, where can I find the introduction of typing in this webset? thank you

Exercise7.13 Let\[f\left( x \right) = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 1} {{c_i}{x^{{q^i}}} \in {\Bbb{F}_q}[x]} \]

Prove the f is a permutation polynomial of \[{\Bbb{F}_{{q^n}}}\] if and only if \[\gcd \left( {\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 1} {{c_i}{x^i},{x^n} - 1} } \right) = 1\] 
I think there is a Theorem , in the front of the Exercise ,that is helpful to solve this exercise. Theorem 7.10 : Let \[r \in N\]with \[\gcd \left( {r,q - 1} \right) = 1\] and let  s  be a positive divisor of \[q-1.\] Let \[g \in {\Bbb{F}_q}\left[ x \right]\] be such that\[g\left( {{x^s}} \right)\]has no nonzero root in $\Bbb{F}_q$. Then \[f\left( x \right)={{x}^{r}}{{\left( g\left( {{x}^{s}} \right) \right)}^{{\left( q-1 \right)}/{s}\;}}\] is a permutation polynomial.

(And I do not know how to use the condtion of the exercise.)

Comment: Which book are you referring to? It seems to me that this question can be resolved by using the theory of linearized polynomials. Most notably by the relation of conventional and linearized associates (and the known relation between their gcds).

Comment: You did fine with the typesetting. I did a bit of fine-tuning. I also switched the notation of the field from $F_q$ to $\Bbb{F}_q$. This is what the gang here seems to prefer, but I'm indifferent myself. If you don't like that change, just click the edit button and revert it (or ask me to do it:-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution comes from the theory of linearized polynomials. See e.g. [Lidl & Niederreiter](http://books.google.fi/books/about/Finite_Fields.html?id=xqMqxQTFUkMC&redir_esc=y). I describe the main steps.

The first thing we observe that the polynomial $f(x)$ is $q$-linear. If we denote the algebraic closure of $\Bbb{F}_q$ by $\overline{F}$, then the polynomial mapping $f:\overline{F}\to\overline{F}$ is linear over the field $\Bbb{F}_q$. In other words, we have
$$
f(\alpha x+\beta y)=\alpha f(x)+\beta f(y)
$$
for all $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb{F}_q$ and all $x,y\in\overline{F}$. This is because $f$ is an $\Bbb{F}_q$-linear combination of the powers of the Frobenius automorphism $x\mapsto x^q$ that fixes elements of $\Bbb{F}_q$ elementwise. Clearly the restriction of this polynomial mapping to $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ maps this extension field to itself.

So this polynomial mapping is a linear transformation of an $n$-dimensional space over $\Bbb{F}_q$ to itself. From elementary linear algebra we recall that such a mapping is bijective (i.e. a permutation) if and only if it is non-singular. Or equivalently that its kernel is trivial.

The elements of $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ are precisely the roots of another $q$-linearized polynomial $g(x)=x^{q^n}-x$. The elements of the kernel of $f\mid_{\Bbb{F}_{q^n}}$ are thus exactly the zeros of
$$h(x)=\gcd(x^{q^n}-x,f(x)).\qquad(*)$$
Thus the said kernel is trivial if and only if $h(x)=x$.

To find a necessary and sufficient condition for $(*)$ we use the theory of conventional and linearized associates of $q$-linearized polynomials. If we are given a (conventional) polynomial $p(x)=\sum_{0\le i\le m}p_ix^i\in\Bbb{F}_q[x]$, then we call the $q$-linearized polynomial
$$
\tilde{p}(x)=\sum_{i=0}^mp_ix^{q^i}
$$
the *linearized associate of* $p(x)$. Similarly we call $p(x)$ the *conventional associate of* $\tilde{p}(x)$. A general result (see Lidl&Niederreiter) that you may be expected to use here is that passing to the linearized associates commutes with forming the greates common divisor. Or
$$
\gcd(p_1(x),p_2(x))=p_3(x)\Longleftrightarrow \gcd(\tilde{p_1}(x),\tilde{p_2}(x))=\tilde{p_3}(x).
$$

This result settles your question immediately. After all, the given $f(x)$ is the linearized associate of $\sum_ic_ix^i$, and $g(x)$ is the linearized associate of
$x^n-1$. Thus $(*)$ gives
$$\gcd(f,g)=x=\tilde{1}\Longleftrightarrow \gcd(x^n-1,\sum_ic_ix^i)=1.
$$

Comment: We clearly don't need the full power of the gcd-result $(*)$. Thinking about a shortcut. Also, this answer is not very useful, if you haven't seen that piece of theory :-(

Comment: whether you can read this comment , all i want to say is  "thanks" for fixing my type mistakes and  a long piece solution.it takes time to understand your solution, and i am reading chapter 3-4 Linearized Polynomials in"Finite Fields" you recommend.

Comment: @ElfPath: This site works nicely in the sense that the "owner" of a post (a question or an answer) is automatically alerted to all the comments under that post. If there are several posters commenting in the same thread, you can single out one of them by adding an at-sign in front of their username (see the beginning of this comment). This is sometimes appropriately called *at-pinging*. Welcome to the site. You will quickly learn the ropes.

Comment: Alas, I haven't thought of a shortcut here. The things that I tried seem to rely on "symbolic factorization" (or the variant of Euclidean algorithm for linearized polynomials) that is explained in Lidl&Niederreiter. If you have that book, you will do fine here I think :-)

Comment: i have read some theorems in chapter 3-4 Linearized Polynomials, and i have understood your solution. i am grateful for your introduction of the linearized polynomials. You remind me of reviewing earlier text. i do not know whether i have express my appreciation properly

Comment: Glad to hear that you understood it! I don't want to sound like pushing you into acts of appreciation - just to make sure that you are informed:-) The site software provides several ways of showing appreciation: the asker (also know as the OP, or the Original Poster) of a question has the right to *accept* an answer by clicking the checkmark adjacen to an answer. This awards that answerer 15 reputation points (and also awards the asker themselves 2 reputation points). Another way to show appreciation is to *upvote* an answer. But to do that you must have earned a few dozen rep points first.

Comment: (cont'd) Upvoting an answer and a question is open to all members who have earned that privilege. The bulk of the reputation points members have earned on the site comes from other readers giving their nod of approval by upvoting questions/answers. Reputation is a two-edged motivator. Earning rep gives a user certain privileges (read the help files yourself), but it also has the side-effect of turning the site to one gigantic ego trip (guilty as charged), which in turn leads to occasionallly heated discussion on the Meta-site. You have been warned :-)

Comment: (cont'd) Normally it is recommended that you do not accept one of the answers too early. The reason for this is the following. Accepting an answer signals to the community that you consider your question solved. This in turn deters some (but not too many) members from looking at your question (don't ask me why - this does not work for me, but I've been told that many others only look at questions without an accepted answer). So if you wait for a day or so, you may get better answers from somebody else, and then have more answers to choose the best from!